# How to filter words using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I've got a little problem with my code. I want to filter all Words with a vowel and 5 letters in total out of a text and put them into a string array.

The length of the array has to be total count of matches in the text and the string array should be overprinted. Admittedly it doesn't work. Any tips or improvements?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class probe {

    public static String[] extractWords(String text) {

        String pattern = "//[aeiou]\\w{4}\\s";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        int i = 0;

        String[] F = new String[i];
        i = F.length;

        do {
            i++;

        } while (m.find()); //Matches=Länge array

        while (m.find()) {
            String trefferText = m.group();
            F = new String[]{trefferText};
        }

        return F;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "";
        String[] Ausgabe = probe.extractWords(text);

        for (String s : Ausgabe) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using external tools to get your regex right first, for instance [this one](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php) (note the 'explain' option). What your regex says now is // followed by either one of [aeiou] and other 4 letters and a whitespace. So that would match `//abcde<space>` but not `//abcde` (missing whitespace) and not `//bacde<space>` (vowel is not the first letter), not probably what you want. If you want total 5 letters and at least one vowel you will need what is called a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So, an example would be something like that:

```
\w{5}(?<=[aeiou])\b
```

(I also suggest using word boundary `\b` for breaking words, not whitespaces).

After you get your regex right in an external tool, you could start solving your problem in the code, I'd suggest writing test cases of expected results for different inputs as a first step, and then comparing results your program produces with test cases (via assertions/logging/debug etc.).